# Netbeans 8.0.2, Codeigniter 2.2.0, XDebug Breakpoints Not Working

Tags: php, codeigniter, netbeans, breakpoints, xdebug

So I have just installed Netbeans and I have opened an existing project that has been written with Codeigniter.
I cant seem to get the debug tool working. Can anyone help me out?
Ive spent the last couple of hours looking online and cant find any definitive resource that solves the problem.
I need to be able to debug this project and I can't understand why this doesn't just work out of the box.

Ive a fresh Codeigniter install, Xampp server 1.8.3.5, OSX

Loaded Configuration File: /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/php.ini

Comment: Show use your config/phpinfo etc... cant help without sufficient information.

Comment: If a change in the "php.ini" has no effect, it's possible PHP is using a different one. You can verify this with phpinfo(). Go to the URI http://localhost/xampp/phpinfo.php and search for "Loaded Configuration File". This value shows you the "php.ini" PHP is really using.

Comment: **Note:** After changing the "php.ini" you have to restart Apache so that Apache/PHP can read the new settings.

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola Do I need to change something in this php.ini file? Or should I paste its contents into my question?

Comment: Show content only regarding `xdebug` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To configure `php.ini` file. So open /Applications/XAMPP/etc/php.ini with your favorite editor and add the lines to the bottom of it:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension=/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20121212/xdebug.so
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

For the reference check this out: http://blog.laaz.org/tech/2010/08/27/xdebug-with-xampp-on-mac-os-x/